# Varying of horizontal velocity in a projectile motion

Tags: kinematics, projectile

We know that horizontal component of  velocity in ideal projectile motion is constant.
But my doubt was, if the comp. is Vcos(theta) then while going up theta decreases thus cos ratio should increase resulting in increase of horizontal velocity how is that possible???

Comment: v_x should be v_0 cos(theta_0). You are right that as the object flies, the angle changes. but so does the *total* speed! this means that the x-component remains constant

Comment: Thanks alot for answering. I later understood it was a silly question to ask

Comment: Not a problem:) happy to help